# Windows Universal 8.1 - Uploading File to the Server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Task to POST(upload a photo) the Photo to the Server.
    I tried Posting it from "Advanced Rest Client", it works fine.
    Status 
    200 OK and photo is uploaded.
    Post Url : http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/photo/api/upload.php?d=Multimedia/shared
    and added a Image file, the file name should be "files"
    PFA @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8cv5.png

```
And here is what all I tried from my code
1. Background Uploader
path = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/photo/api/upload.php?d=Multimedia/shared";

Uri uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
uploader.SetRequestHeader("files", file.Name);
UploadOperation upload = uploader.CreateUpload(uri, file);
await HandleUploadAsync(upload, true);

Not Working.

2. http POST method

HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(RequestUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);
myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), myRequest);

 private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
            writeMultipartObject_dictOfObj(postStream, postParam_dictOfObj);
            postStream.Dispose();

            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
        }

public void writeMultipartObject_dictOfObj(Stream stream,object data,string fileName)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            if (data != null)
            {
                foreach (var entry in data as Dictionary<string, object>)
                {
                    WriteEntry(writer, entry.Key, entry.Value, fileName);
                }
            }

            writer.Write(boundary);
            writer.Flush();
        }

        private void WriteEntry(StreamWriter writer,string key, object value, string fileName)
        {
            Stream output = writer.BaseStream;

            if (value != null)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(boundary);
                if (value is byte[])
                {
                    byte[] ba = value as byte[];
                    writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Dis-data; name=""{0}""; filename=""{1}""", key, fileName);
                    writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Type:application/octet-stream");
                    writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Length: " + ba.Length);
                    writer.WriteLine();
                    output.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
                    output.Flush();
                    writer.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Dis-data; name=""{0}""", key);
                    writer.WriteLine();
                    writer.WriteLine(value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

   private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                String Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
           }
       }

This also not working.

I tried with all the answers I got from Stack Overflow and MSDN blogs but couldn't find the Solution to my problem. So please help me resolve this issue or suggest any other options.

Thanks in Advance
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not sending the request in the format the server is expecting. I recommend you to try with `HttpMultipartFormDataContent` or `MultipartFormDataContent`:

#### WinRT

```
HttpMultipartFormDataContent multipartContent =
    new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();

multipartContent.Add(
    new HttpStreamContent(inputStream),
    "myFile",
    file.Name);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
    uri,
    multipartContent);
```

#### .NET

```
Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

MultipartFormDataContent multipartContent =
    new MultipartFormDataContent();

multipartContent.Add(
    new StreamContent(stream),
    "myFile",
    file.Name);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
    uri,
    multipartContent);
```

Comment: #kiewic Thanks but My Project is Universal 8.1 and my Service layer is a PCL project. In PCL we don't have System.Net.Http.HttpClient instead we have Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient where PostAsync Method accepts two parameters 1. URI 2.  IHttpContent instead of HttpMultipartFormDataContent. So I have to achieve this with Windows.Web.Http Libraray

Comment: #kiewic Pls check the Code that I have written using HttpStreamContent. Is that the right approach ?If not Pls Suggest. Because I am still not able to upload the file into the Server Successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is this Approach right ?

 HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());
 streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
 streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
 streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"" + flKey +    "\"; filename=\"" + fleNm + "\"");
 Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new     Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Post, uri);
 request.Content = streamContent;
 var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
 var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
 Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(cts.Token);
 String resp = response.ToString();
```